# Building Apache Ranger from source gives ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)

Tags: java, maven, apache-ranger

I'am trying to build apache ranger manually from source. But during the process build fails with following error

```
Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive schema-registry-plugin: IOException when zipping rMETA-INF/maven/org.apache.ranger/ranger-distro/pom.xml: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

The following command is used for building

```
mvn -DskipJSTests clean compile package install
```

The failure happens for the package `Apache Ranger Distribution`

But if I run the command as below the build succeeds.

```
mvn -DskipJSTests clean compile package install  -P ranger-trino-plugin
```

The java version that I use is Java 11.

Not sure if the error is related to this [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/RANGER-3755) in Jira.

I tried deleting .m2 repository but it doesn't help. Can someone help me understand why this is happening?